# How to make conditional where based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to make where clause conditional based on another column. I tried the below code but it gives syntax error

```
SELECT *
FROM   jobs
WHERE  CASE
         WHEN "jobs"."tags" IS NOT NULL
              AND "jobs"."isprivate" = 1 THEN (
         Concat(',', "jobs"."tags", ',') LIKE '%,Test,%'
          OR
         Concat(',', "jobs"."tags", ',') LIKE '%,natures_touch_fork_lift,%' )
         ELSE 1 = 1
       END;
```

In the above code, I want search tags only the job is private and the tag has data

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? AND I think the problem is on  `OR` which is after the `THEN`

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement* - it returns a value, it doesn't allow you to conditionally run a statement. Just try standard AND/OR logic. I should also mention that this will be very bad for performance because by using the `concat` function on the column in your where clause you make the query unsargable, i.e. unable to use indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `CASE` expression here actually:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM jobs
WHERE (isprivate = 1 AND (
           ',' + tags + ',' LIKE '%,Test,%' OR
           ',' + tags + ',' LIKE '%,natures_touch_fork_lift,%'
      )) OR isprivate = 0;
```

Note that you should *avoid* storing the tags as CSV.  Instead, persist each tag value in a separate record.  The above query should be viewed a temporary workaround and used long term only if you cannot control the table structure.

Comment: Maybe when OP upgrades from SQL Server 2008 they can normalise their tables? :)